# Unity Modify startup screen resolutions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, resolutions

## Is it possible to remove some of the resolutions from the Unity startup menu, and if so, how?

I want to do this because my game doesn't work on all of the resolutions that unity gives the user access to. For example, on [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24H9y.png) I would want to remove the currently selected resolution so it can't get accessed.

I have already tried searching google but I only came up with how to remove the startup screen entirely. I don't want this; I still want the user to be able to select resolutions on startup but want to remove specific resolutions from the dropdown.

Comment: Sry for my bad english any mods on this stackoverflow i would be thankfull if you could edit the wrong spelled things and bad grammar :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called the Resolution Dialog and below is an instruction on how to disable that.

**1**.Go to *File* ---> *Build Settings...*.

**2**.Select your platform (*PC, Mac & Linux Standalone*)

**3**.Click *Player Settings...* then Click on *Resolution and Presentation*

**4**.On the *Display Resolution Dialog*, change that to *Disabled* .

---

[image]

---

Can be done from script like below: (Editor only)

```
PlayerSettings.displayResolutionDialog = ResolutionDialogSetting.Disabled;
```

> is it possible i can dissable only a few of the resolutions options
>   from the startup menu?

*No*. There is no known way to add/remove whatever resolution `Resolution Dialog` displays.

The solution is to make your own Resolution Dialog with Unity's UI and Dropdown menu and program it to whatever resolution you want. You can then use [`Screen.SetResolution`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen.SetResolution.html) to change the resolution to the selected one from your own custom Resolution Dialog.

For example:

```
Screen.SetResolution(selectedWidth, selectedHeight, true);
```

Comment: I know that i can disable it but is it possible i can dissable only a few of the resolutions options from the startup menu?

Comment: @Programmer looks like there is no more such option in 2019.3?